# how to install "snappy(x86-64) = 1.0.5-1.el6" on cents?

Tags: hadoop, centos, hortonworks-data-platform, snappy

When I try to install DataNode in hadoop server it says gthe following error,

```
Fail: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install snappy-devel' returned 1. Error: Package: snappy-devel-1.0.5-1.el6.x86_64 (HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.19)
       Requires: snappy(x86-64) = 1.0.5-1.el6
       Installed: snappy-1.1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
           snappy(x86-64) = 1.1.0-1.el6
       Available: snappy-1.0.5-1.el6.x86_64 (HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.19)
           snappy(x86-64) = 1.0.5-1.el6
```

So can anyone help me to resolve this?

Thank You.

Comment: Does it work if you run `yum install snappy snappy-devel`? yum should be figuring that sort of dependency upgrade out for you so I'm not sure why it isn't doing that.

Comment: @EtanReisner I did that, but getting the same error. :(

Comment: Instead of `-d0 -e0` try `-d10 -e10` (for very verbose output) and see what the output tells you is going on.

Comment: @EtanReisner tried, but no luck. Still getting the same error…:(

Comment: No extra error content? There should be significantly more output with those flags can you include it in the post?

Answer (score 2):

Requires: snappy(x86-64) = 1.0.5-1.el6    <=== This line indicates that the **1.0.5-1.el6 version of snappy is required**.

Installed: **snappy-1.1.0-1.el6.x86_64** (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5) <== This line says that the 1.1.0-1.el6.x86_64 version is already installed.

Therefore, you have a newer version of the snappy package installed, which is causing this issue.Hadoop requires the snappy-devel package that is a lower version that what is on the machine already. Run the following on the host and retry.

```
yum remove snappy
yum install snappy-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

I got over this problem by deleting the already installed package snappy.

for centos you can use the command

**yum remove snappy**